# Why does my background flicker through my meshes in DirectX 12 Release build?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, directx-12

I have been developing this game in C++ in Visual Studio using DirectX 12. I used the Debug build configuration during development and the graphics were smooth as butter.

When I was preparing to publish the game on the Windows Store so I could share it with friends as play testers, I switched to Release build configuration. As soon as I did that I started getting this flicker of the back-ground color coming through my wall meshes.

[Here is a short video](https://youtu.be/Xzr7uUmZbeU) that shows the flicker.
[Here is a longer video](https://youtu.be/JOw0PfF-XOQ) that I made before switching to Release build configuration that shows there is no flicker.

I am new to DirectX 12. This project was my teacher. I studied Microsoft's [Direct3D 12 Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn903821), and I studied the DirectX 12 templates in Visual Studio. 
I felt quite pleased that I was able to master DirectX 12 well enough to produce this game as well as I did. Then the Release thing, and the flicker thing, and I am at a loss.

Is this likely to be a shader issue? or a command queue issue? or a texture issue? or something else?

Comment: Could be a number of things.
Is your generic background colour yellow?
Otherwise it could be something to do with normals.
possibly the vertices are being interpreted backwards.
What changed between the debug build and the release build?

Comment: @Slipoch, yes, the generic background color is yellow. I made it yellow for the video so it would stand out. 

The only significant difference between the Debug build and the Release build is in the vcxproj file, the Debug section has `<UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>` and `<UseDotNetNativeToolchain>false</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>` and the Release section has `<UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>` and `<UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>`.

Comment: Only significant difference? so if you just change these two lines back the flicker disappears?

Comment: I just ran a few tests, and I was mistaken. The `<UseDotNetNativeToolchain>` has no effect, but the `<UseDebugLibraries>` is the one that makes the difference. It's just one line, but that one line tells the compiler to use a whole different set of libraries, no?

Comment: Yeah, as Chuck below stated it could be a timing issue, the debug libraries may be using a low refresh rate, the release libraries may be trying to go to higher refresh rates.

Are the areas where the bits are disappearing consistant? ie: when you look at them from a certain angle they are no longer there. Is it always the same spots?

Answer (score 3):

DirectX 12 is an API designed for graphics experts and provides a great deal of application control compared to say Direct3D 11. The cost of that control is that you the application developer are responsible for getting *everything* right, making sure it works across a broad range of hardware, and robustly handling stress scenarios and error cases all yourself.

There are numerous ways you can get 'blinking' effects in DirectX 12. A common one is failure to keep your graphics memory with constants, IBs, VBs, etc. unchanged between the time you call `Draw` and the time the actual draw completes on the GPU which often happens a few frames later. This synchronization is a key challenge of using the API properly. For an example solution, see `GraphicsMemory` in [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started).

> If you are new to DirectX development, I strongly advise starting with DirectX 11. It's basically the same functionality, but takes care of buffer renaming, resource barriers, fences, VRAM overcommit, etc.

Comment: If this was the issue, wouldn't this occur with the debug libraries as well as the release libraries?

Comment: With timing-related issues, maybe or maybe not.